# Lollipop plot for dataframe with two groups

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, stem-plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
                   Country variable      value
0                 Afghanistan     Area  38.232510
1                 Afghanistan     Yield  70.081666
2                   Argentina     Area  96.776730
3                   Argentina     Area  60.047651
4                   Argentina     Yield  66.811117
..                        ...      ...        ...
133  United States Of America    Yield  53.536069
134  United States Of America    Area   76.975885
135  United States Of America    Yield  19.987656
136                    Zambia    Yield  39.493612
137                    Zambia    Yield  35.384809
```

I want to use it to construct a lollipop graphic (e.g. https://python-graph-gallery.com/184-lollipop-plot-with-2-groups/). However, the example dataframe is different from mine in that it has two values for each group while I want to plot the minimum and maximum value for the two groups for each country, with the group being differentiated by hue. How can I do it by modifying the code from that example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make a good starting point to refine from:

```py
df_agg = df.groupby(['Country', 'variable']).agg([min, max]).droplevel(level=0, axis=1).reset_index()

colours = { 
    'Area' : { 'line' : 'pink', 'min' : 'crimson', 'max' : 'red' }, 
    'Yield' : { 'line' : 'skyblue', 'min' : 'navy', 'max' : 'blue' }, 
}

vars = df_agg['variable'].unique()

for var in vars:
    df_plt = df_agg[df_agg['variable'] == var]
    
    my_range = list(df_plt.index)
    
    plt.hlines(y=my_range, xmin=df_plt['min'], xmax=df_plt['max'], color=colours[var]['line'], alpha=0.4)
    plt.scatter(df_plt['min'], my_range, color=colours[var]['min'], alpha=1, label=f'{var} min')
    plt.scatter(df_plt['max'], my_range, color=colours[var]['max'], alpha=1, label=f'{var} max')

# Add legend, title and axis names
plt.legend()
plt.yticks(df_agg.index, df_agg['Country'])
plt.title("Min and Max per Country", loc='left')
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.ylabel('Country')

# Show the graph
plt.show()
```

For the data in your question, this gives:
[image]

You can also "group" the country values by making the `my_range` value float around an integer value based on `Country`, then only putting y ticks at those integer values:

```
df_agg = df.groupby(['Country', 'variable']).agg([min, max]).droplevel(level=0, axis=1).reset_index()

colours = { 
    'Area' : { 'line' : 'pink', 'min' : 'crimson', 'max' : 'red' }, 
    'Yield' : { 'line' : 'skyblue', 'min' : 'navy', 'max' : 'blue' }, 
}

countries = list(df_agg['Country'].unique())

vars = df_agg['variable'].unique()

# figure out y positions for each lollipop
# make them go from y-0.2 to y+0.2
plot_y = { var : pt for var, pt in zip(vars, np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2, num=len(vars))) }
    
for var in vars:
    df_plt = df_agg[df_agg['variable'] == var]
    
    my_range = list(df_plt['Country'].apply(countries.index) + plot_y[var])
    
    plt.hlines(y=my_range, xmin=df_plt['min'], xmax=df_plt['max'], color=colours[var]['line'], alpha=0.4)
    plt.scatter(df_plt['min'], my_range, color=colours[var]['min'], alpha=1, label=f'{var} min')
    plt.scatter(df_plt['max'], my_range, color=colours[var]['max'], alpha=1, label=f'{var} max')

# Add legend, title and axis names
plt.legend()
plt.yticks(range(len(countries)), countries)
plt.title("Min and Max per Country", loc='left')
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.ylabel('Country')

# Show the graph
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I should have clarified in my question, but I do have both Area and Yield Values for each country, therefore I want to show the 2 lollipops for each country, perhaps by jittering them a bit like in a seaborn boxplot

Comment: updated sample dataset to reflect that

Comment: @user308827 the code will deal with that, you should see the two lollipops next to each other in the y direction

Comment: @user308827 I've updated the image to show what you get for the updated data in your question

Comment: Looks great! Is there a way to avoid the duplication of the country name and just plot the two lollipops for each country close enough so that the user knows they correspond to the same country?

Comment: @user308827 well, I was going to say that was beyond my matplotlib knowledge, but then I figured out a way to do it. See my edit...

Comment: Perfect, I will accept this soln.

Comment: @user308827 glad I could help.